# (Windows 10) PuTTY - something blocks port tunnel

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty, tunnel

I'm stuck and don't know why the port tunnel doesn't work on Windows with PuTTY.

- I have established an SSH connection with the following port forwarding `8000:localhost:80`: 
   [image: Screenshot 1]
- On the remote host, I have a GUI interface exposed on port `80` and everything was working fine, however currently the tunnel is established, I cannot see the UI, and the request for `localhost:8000` is pending all the time: 
   [image: Screenshot 2]
- Disabling Windows Firewall doesn't work, whereas everything works fine on Linux:

  ```
  ssh -L 8000:localhost:80
  ```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have no reputation to post screens : (

Comment: try to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 to see if that makes a difference. Maybe the resolver does not resolve localhost properly?

Comment: If you add links to the screenshots, someone with rep will likely embed them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot doesn't match the information in your post. You say that you have configured the server's `localhost` as the tunnel's destination, but your PuTTY screenshot lists `111.111.111.111`. Whether it's literally that address or some other global address – even if it's the server's *own* address – it's still not the same thing as `localhost`.

It is possible for a program to only listen for connections on a specific local address – so in your case it's very likely that the app on your server is listening on loopback addresses only.

Comment: It was fake IP. Excuse me

Comment: Doesn't matter much if it's fake; the point is _it's different from the localhost IP_. (And if you actually decided to replace "localhost" with a fake IP, then ....)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 and couldn't get the PuTTY tunnel set up, but knew everything was running properly since I could run the typical SSH tunnel command on my Mac and everything worked fine.

I ended up installing BitVise, which is also on the PuTTY website, then used this [site](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-create-ssh-tunnel-with-bitvise-ssh-client-a-better-alternative-to-putty):

- Important settings:

  - 1st tab → Login → Add Host: Name of the computer to connect to and username
  - 7th tab → CS2: 
     Listen Interface: `127.0.0.1` Listen Port: `5901` 
     Destination Host: `localhost` Dest Port: `5901`

Comment: If a tunnel wasn't working in PuTTY, then it was due to being improperly configured in PuTTY.